# VLAN tagging: duplicated packets

Tags: networking, vlan

I have a problem with VLAN tagging. I am completely newbie about VLAN so maybe there is something I misunderstood at all...

Basically: I have a Linux box configured via `/etc/network/interfaces` as:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.70.31
   netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug eth0.0001
iface eth0.0001 inet static
   address 192.168.1.31
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I adjusted the routing table so that now I have (output of `ip r` command):

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0.0001 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.31
192.168.70.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.70.31
```

If I monitor packets with Wireshark while pinging another host tagged with VLAN ID 1 (192.168.1.30 in my test) then I see that my host emits duplicated packets, one *with* the proper VLAN ID and another one (coming out from the same 192.168.1.31 interface!) *without* the VLAN tag. The other host responds to both packets, respectively with and without the proper VLAN tag, as you can see in the screenshot here below:

[image: Wireshark capture screenshot]

The question is: why is my host emitting duplicated packets? If pinging another host in 192.168.1.x network, shouldn't it only emit *one* packet with the proper VLAN tag (`1` in my case)?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't ask Wireshark to monitor ALL interfaces? Then duplication is normal. Please check using `tcpdump` instead so we get text rather than screenshot). Example: `tcpdump -n -l -e -p -i eth0` versus `tcpdump -n -l -e -p -i eth0.0001`. Both will have about the same, but there will be a vlan tag in first.

Comment: @A.B: Yes, sure: I've exactly asked Wireshark to monitor ALL interfaces... but if so, probably I am missing something... I mean: how many packets are actually trasmitted "on the wire"? Only the one with VLAN tag specified? And the other one is only coming out in Wireshark due to some black magic in packets handling?

Comment: Made an answer hopefully explaining successfully why this is normal.

Comment: I think this also warrants a link to [PSA: Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Those color effects on the photo are hideous, and make the contents hard to read. Ok, not much of an issue here, since the text mostly just repeats, but, really, at least take a screenshot instead of a photo, please. :/

Comment: @ilkkachu: you are right but, believe me, with the setup I had at the moment of posting the request taking a photo was the quickest option I had

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only *one* physical interface: `eth0`. Any virtual interface (here: `eth0.0001`) linked to the actual interface is showing encapsulated traffic in its virtual view until the traffic is emitted through the actual interface.

The network stack will make such traffic move through each interface until it reaches the final interface where it leaves the machine. Each step can be captured separately, leading to multiple captures of the same payload, but with different encapsulation properties.

So here what happens (in a very simplified view) as visible with Wireshark:

- the VLAN interface is showing the payload withing the VLAN frame, so doesn't show any VLAN

  This virtual interface is the one participating in routing with regard to IP LAN 192.168.1.0/24. An IP packet is emitted, and is itself encapsulated inside a (normal) Ethernet frame. (Before this could be done ARP traffic would also have happened, but is not in the capture). This frame is captured by Wireshark before being given to the network part handling VLAN interfaces.
- the `eth0` interface is showing the *encapsulated* payload, so shows VLAN ID 1.

  The previous Ethernet frame in `eth0.0001` gets encapsulated with an additional VLAN tag (adding 4 bytes to the frame) once reaching `eth0` and is captured, again but not the same, by Wireshark before being given to the actual NIC's hardware by the NIC's driver.

Wireshark (nor `tcpdump` for this very simple case) doesn't stop at the first layer but displays more: IPv4 decoding with addresses and IP protocol (ICMP).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, thanks to comment from A.B which put me on the right way...

I was capturing *ALL* interfaces in Wireshark, so in the capture both packets from the raw device (eth0) and from the virtual device (eth0.0001) were shown...

So basically when you send a packet to 192.168.1.x then it is routed on virtual interface eth0.0001 (without VLAN tag); the virtual interface adds the VLAN TAG and "transfer it" to the "raw" interface (eth0 in my case) which actually sends it on the wire... Asking Wireshark to show all interfaces, the packets were listed twice (one from virtual interface and one from raw interface).

**UPDATE**: @A.B posted his own answer a few minutes later, which explains the topic much better than me... please refer to his answer (upvoted and accepted)

Comment: This is a comment more than and answer. I suggest you to add it as a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: @migrc: if you carefully read the post, you'll discover that me and A.B almost simultaneously wrote an answer... then I accepted A.B's answer (which seemed much more complete) but at that point my answer was already posted... and so I simply updated it for making clear what happened (see "UPDATE" note here above)... ideally I could delete my own answer, but it did not seem to a good idea, since that would have broken some reference to the posted answer, it somebody ever linked that (I could really not know)